# Correct Linux user home directory file ownership

Tags: linux, bash, directory, permissions, file-permissions

I would like to programmatically repair the ownership on Linux systems for files within each users home directory which reside under `/home`. From https://serverfault.com/a/146709/75044 the script below seems ideal except, some of the users are not in the `/etc/passwd` as they are externally authenticated.

The users which are externally authenticated, do have a uid and gid associated with their home directories though. The externally authenticated users `uid` and `gid` produced from the `id` command do not match the `ls -ln` respective group and user id. I did not catch this originally due to sanitizing the output. A mapping is being performed so the only way to correctly perform this in my opinion is to leverage the `uid` and `gid` from the directory listing.

Instead of depending on the `/etc/passwd`, how can we obtain and use the `uid` and `gid` from each users home directory to then recursively apply the same uid and gid ownership to the objects within their respective home directories?

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=':' read -r login pass uid gid uname homedir comment; do
    if [[ "$homedir" = **/home/** ]]; then
        if [ -d "$homedir" ]; then
            echo chown -R $uid:$gid "$homedir";
        fi
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

An example user that's external authenticated would have a home directory that lives user `/home`

```
drwx------+  3 DOMAIN\user        DOMAIN\DOMAIN USERS  4096 Jan  1  1969 user
```

but in it's uid/gid format would look like:

```
drwx------+  3 12345        01234  4096 Jan  1  1969 user
```

Output from `id` (the uid/gid does not match the directory listing):

```
$ id DOMAIN\\user
uid=2000234(DOMAIN) gid=2000349(DOMAIN\domain users) groups=2056789(DOMAIN\domain users) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

```
$ stat -c "%n %u:%g" /home/user/
/home/user/ 12345:01234
```

I assume it would be easier to obtain and apply using the uid and gid verse parsing the user and group names.

An example of a local user is as follows:

```
drwx------.  4  1000  1000  4096 Jul 21 02:04 user2

drwx------.  4 user2           user2          4096 Jul 21 02:04 user2
```

```
$ id user2
uid=1000(user2) gid=1000(user2) groups=1000(user2),4(adm),190(systemd-journal)
```

**edit**

Another option would be to list the file in `/home`, feed through `stat` and apply the permissions to those files that do not match. An example to just change the group would be

`find /home -maxdepth 1` but we do not want to include /home in the listing
`stat -c %g` against home directory and set to variable $GID
`find \! -gid $GID -exec chown :$GID {} \;` if $GID for a child file or folder of the home directory does not match, fix it

Something like the following *which does not work* would suffice

```
find . -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    GID=$(stat -c %g)
    chown :$GID $f
' find-sh {} \;
```

Comment: Do the home directories always have the same name as the username? Or can you derive the username from the home directory name? Then a loop over all directories in `/home` and the command `id username` might help.

Comment: The home directories do have the same username in the sense of `/home/user` but the actual username and group, are more complex because they represent the actual full username and group, e.g. `domain\user` and `domain\domain group` which I feel may be more complex to parse then the uid and gid. I will update the question to more fully explain.

Comment: Do you have only one domain? Please show the output of `id user` and `id DOMAIN\\user`.

Comment: Yes, only one domain. Out from running id for my user account: `uid=12345(DOMAIN\user) gid=01234(DOMAIN\domain users)`

Comment: Please show in your question both commands (with and without domain) with the corresponding output both for a local user and for a domain user. Can the home directory `/home/user` have a wrong owner? Please add all requested information to your question.

Comment: The user home directories themselves should not have a wrong owner. We assume the uid and gid of `/home/user` for each home directory are definitive.

Comment: Please add all requested information to the question. (I assumed with your reputation you should know this.) You still did not show the `id` commands. I need this information to check if my idea for a solution would work. Unfortunately I don't have a Linux system with domain users, so I cannot do this check on my computer.

Comment: Realized the `id` command produces a mapped value to the value to the system `ls -ln` output which are not the same. I failed to catch that when sanitizing output.

Comment: Replacing the numbers instead of copying and pasting prevents us from seeing a possible relation between the values. I think the only sensitive information might be the domain and user names. The numbers are only relevant for your system/domain. If the owner uid in `ls -lnd /home/user` differs from `id user`, are there files or subdirectiories with a matching uid? Please show the output of `stat -c "%n %u:%g" /home/user` for a domain user.

Comment: Yes, the `ls` and `id` commands uid and gid's differ for the same user. The subdirectories and files under a users home directory match that of the home directory owner. `stat` output added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the owner and group of all home directories match the corresponding user, you can set the ownership for all contained subdirectories and files to the same values.

Note that there might be files or directories that deliberately have a different owner or group. Blindly changing the owner or group might break access for other users or applications.

This (untested) command will *show* the commands to recursively change the owner and group IDs to the values taken from the home directory:

```
for i in /home/*/
do
    echo chown -Rh $(stat -c "%u:%g" "$i") "$i"
done
```

You can also use `chown --reference=RFILE` to copy the ownership data from a reference, but this will not show the actual uid and gid values.

```
for i in /home/*/
do
    echo chown -Rh --reference="$i" "$i"
done
```

When you have manually checked that everything is correct, remove the `echo` to actually run the commands.

Answer (score 0):

The chown command takes either the name or id (string or numeric) for both the  user and group, i.e.:

```
  chown root:staff /some/file
  or
  chown 0:20 /some/file
```

Simply running an `ls -l` on `/home` directory will show you the user and group name of the owner of each home directory. If you wanted the numeric version you could just do `ls -ln`

From there it is just a case of reformatting the output into a sequence of `chown` commands. You could do that manually or using something like `sed`, i.e.:

```
sed -E 's/^.{15} *([^ ]*) *([^ ]*) *[0-9]*.{14}(.*)$/chown -R \1:\2 \3/g'
```

Note: I am not going to guarantee that that particular RegEx is perfect, there  were a couple of edge cases I handled, but there may be more so you may need to tweak the RegEx a bit.

**Edit:** Updating to combine into a one-liner:

```
eval "$( ls -ln | sed -E '1d;s/^.{10} *[0-9]* *([^ ]*) *([^ ]*) *[0-9]*.{14}(.*)$/chown -R \1:\2 \3/g' )"
```

Note: Please test the individual parts of this before running the whole thing as you may have some weird corner case I haven't considered.

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to programmatically recurse through the `/home` directory verse one off.

Comment: Are you saying your home directories are nested i.e. `/home/a/apple` or are they all directly in `/home`, i.e. `/home/apple`?

Comment: Just meaning perform against all user directories under `/home`

Comment: I have added an edit to the answer to make it into a one liner that does the whole directory...

Comment: I believe there's an issue with the regex. First testing with a regular user in a directory that's not a home directory so I do not break things. `# eval "$( ls -ln | sed -E '1d;s/^.{10} *[0-9]* *([^ ]*) *([^ ]*) *[0-9]*.{14}(.*)$/chown -R \1:\2 \3/g' )"
chown: invalid user: ‘.:2’`
This may help:
`# ls -ln
total 4
drwx------. 2 0 0 4096 Jul 21 17:40 test
`